# DSA public key system verification with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, public-key-encryption

I need to verify a DSA signature in Silverlight and since the runtime does not include the System.Security.Cryptography.DSA class I was wondering if anyone has an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not, unless you could find an open source, safe managed code implementation elsewhere that would compile within the BCL subset of Silverlight.